# Completely clean up local opam package after failed installation

Tags: opam

I attempted to install a package from source with `opam install .` in the source directory. The install failed and I have given up on installing it for now. However, opam seems to leave around a bunch of junk related to the package. If I do `opam uninstall` or `opam remove`, it says the package is not installed and there is nothing to do. `opam clean` also doesn't get rid of it.

I have gone in and deleted a bunch of directories but there still seems to be metadata somewhere. How do I cleanly delete a failed local install?

I am using opam version `2.1.4`.